# AngularJS Controller initialization by state with $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs

I have a controller that is intended to support all CRUD operations of a certain Model: Display the list of records, show details of a record, edit, create, update and delete.

Different views are rendered using that same controller - but for each view, a different initialization is required: for the list, I should load a page of records, for a details view - i would load by ID.

What is the best practice to get the "state" of the controller when it is initialized.

Here's an example of a few routes I am using:

```
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // ...

        .when('/activity/list', {
            controller: 'ActivityController',
            templateUrl: 'views/activityList.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .when('/activity/create', {
            controller: 'ActivityController',
            templateUrl: 'views/createNewActivity.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .when('/activity/:id', {
            controller: 'ActivityController',
            templateUrl: 'views/activity.html',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/login' });
}
```

for patch - I distinguished explicitly with checking the path. This can't be the best practice in angular I guess.

```
if ($location.$$path == '/activity/list') {
    initList();
}
```

Comment: can set other properties in route config objects and inspect them through `$route.current` or use a `resolve` to inject variable in controller

Comment: what other properties? the documentation for $routeProvider.when doesn't seem to have a property for that. what am I missing? 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: hmm...I know you used to be able to put properties on those objects....seems you can't anymore but can still use `resolve`. I haven't used `ngroute` for long time always use `ui-router`

Comment: from the lack of activity over this simple question, and your (charliefl's) answer - are you suggesting the industry standard for AngularJS navigation is ui-route and not the native angularJS $routeProvider ?

Comment: answer is probably yes since it is significantly more robust and flexible and supports nested views and parent states. angular router did just go through a major upgrade but that new router isn't `ngroute` like you are using

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way in your situation is to leave controller alone and go with the RestAPI, here is an example how I will do it:

Route file:

```
.when('/tours', {
    templateUrl: 'scripts/partials/pages/tours.partial.html',
    controller: 'TourController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        toursService: function (genericData) {
            return genericData.getTours;
        }
    }
})
.when('/tour/:id', {
    templateUrl: 'scripts/partials/pages/tour-single.html',
    controller: 'TourSingleController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    resolve: {
        toursSingleService: function ($route, genericData) {
            // This will get us the current item with specific ID
            var id = $route.current.params.id;
            return genericData.getTourSingle(id);
        },
    }
})
```

Here is my genericservice.js file:

```
function genericData($resource) {

    // ngResource call to our static data
    var TourSingle = $resource('/api/tour/:id', {'id': '@id'});

    function getListData(RestData) {
        return RestData.query().$promise.then(function(results) {
            return results;
        }, function(error) { // Check for errors
        });
    }

    function getSpecificData(id) {
        return TourSingle.get({'id':id}).$promise.then(function(results) {
            return results;
        }, function(error) { // Check for errors
        });
    }

    return {
        getTours: getListData(TourSingle),
        getTourSingle: getSpecificData,
    }
}
```

This is the controller example:

```
function TourController(toursService) {

    // vm is our capture variable
    var vm = this;

    vm.tours = toursService;
}
```